# how to move the cursor in input field before a specific value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting cursor on end in the field after `@gmail.com`, but I want it before `@gmail.com`. How can I do that?

HTML:

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="{{vals}}" ng-click="val()">
```

AngularJS:

```
$scope.val = function(){
    $scope.vals = "@gmail.com";
};
```

Comment: With the AngularJS framework, one generally use the `ng-model` directive with `<input>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use `setSelectionRange`, but it doesn't work with input `type="email"`.

If you don't mind using `type="name"` (which means you'll have to validate if your input is a valid e-mail yourself), try this:

```html
<input type="name" id="email" value="@gmail.com" onclick="val()">

<script>
  const emailInput = document.getElementById("email")

  const val = () => {
    emailInput.setSelectionRange(0, 0)
  }
</script>
```

Note that this is a pure JavaScript solution.

More about `setSelectionRange` can be seen [MDN Web API Reference - `setSelectionRange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange).